# mysqli and multi_query not working

Tags: php, mysqli

```
 <?php

$mysqli=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","politicalforum");

 $query="SELECT query_title FROM administrator";
  $query.="SELECT thread_id FROM threads";

 if($mysqli->multi_query($query))
 { 
    do
    {

        if($result=$mysqli->store_result())
        {
            while($row=$result->fetch_row())
            {
                printf("%s\n",$row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }

        if($mysqli->more_results())
        {
            print("-------------------------------");
        }
    }while($mysql->next_result());
 }


$mysqli->close();
```

?>

It doesnt work.. it doesnt go to the first if condition that identifies if it is a multiquery..
I have other question, ..why are `multi_query()` is useful..,

UPDATE:

> Strict Standards: mysqli::next_result() [mysqli.next-result]: There is
>   no next result set. Please, call
>   mysqli_more_results()/mysqli::more_results() to check whether to call
>   this function/method in C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum2\test.php on
>   line 42

SOLVED:

```
 <?php

$mysqli=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","politicalforum");

 $query="SELECT query_title FROM administrator;";
  $query.="SELECT thread_id FROM threads;";

 if($mysqli->multi_query($query))
 { 
    do
    {

        if($result=$mysqli->store_result())
        {
            while($row=$result->fetch_row())
            {
                printf("%s<br/>",$row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }

        if($mysqli->more_results())
        {
            print("-------------------------------<br/>");
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<br/>';
        }
    }while($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());
 }


$mysqli->close();
```

?>

Comment: What's the point in running these 2 queries together?

Comment: mysqli_multi_query -> Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon.

You need to add a semicolon between your queries. I personally have never used multi_query so I can't advise you past that

Comment: This is basically copy-pasta from the multi_query PHP documentation page, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php, with minor changes to the query structure.

Comment: true.. I tried to do the example myself

Comment: You should have checked this line too... "Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon. ", while copy-pasting

Comment: lol..I should have.. look at the update .. I get an error when I end executing the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a semicolon at the end of the first query.

```
$query="SELECT query_title FROM administrator;";
$query.="SELECT thread_id FROM threads";
```

[mysqli::multi_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: Strict Standards: mysqli::next_result() [mysqli.next-result]: There is no next result set. Please, call mysqli_more_results()/mysqli::more_results() to check whether to call this function/method in C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum2\test.php on line 42

Comment: what up with that strict standard?!?

Comment: If by "strict standard" you mean the required semicolon, remember you're just putting two strings together.  When your code is run, $query looks like *"SELECT query_title FROM administratorSELECT thread_id FROM threads"*.  Putting the semicolon in there tells SQL that you're done with one statement, and starting another.  As far as it knows, you mean *"administratorSELECT"* is the name of a table ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get this warning, is simply because you use a do...while loop that evaluates the condition after running the command block. So when there are no more results, the contents of the loop are ran one additional time, yielding that warning.

Using a while ($mysql->next_result())...do loop should fix this. (On a general note: Using post-test loops like you did is quite uncommon in database programming)

If code is poetry, I am trying to be Shakespeare!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it like this:

```
if ($res)  {

    do {
      $mycon->next_result();   //// instead of putting it in a while, put it here

        if ($result = $mycon->store_result()) {

            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {

                foreach ($row as $cell)

                    $flag = $cell;
            }

            ///$result->close();
        }   
      $sale=$sale+1;

    }   while ($sale > 2);
}
```

Comment: Please write in english

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer for the same.

please find my function below.

```
public function executeStoredProcedureMulti($strQuery)
{
    $yml    = sfYaml::load(sfConfig::get('sf_config_dir').'/databases.yml');
    $params = $yml['all']['doctrine']['param'];
    $dsnName = $params['dsn'];
    $arrDsn = explode(";",$dsnName);
    $hostName =  explode("=",$arrDsn[0])[1];
    $schemaName = explode("=",$arrDsn[1])[1];
    $this->dbconn = mysqli_connect($hostName, $params['username'], $params['password'], $schemaName);

    //return if connection was created successfully
    if($this->dbconn)
    {
        mysqli_set_charset($this->dbconn,"utf8");
        //return true;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->nErrorNumber = mysqli_connect_errno();
        $this->strErrorDesc = mysqli_connect_error();
        return false;   
    }   


    //check if connection exists
    if($this->dbconn)
    {

        /* close connection */
        //execute the query
        if($this->dbconn->multi_query($strQuery))
        {
            //create table array in dataset object
            $dataSet = array();
            do {
                //store first result set
                if ($result = $this->dbconn->store_result())
                {
                    //create data table passing it the column data
                    $dataTable = new CDataTable($result->fetch_fields());

                    //parse through each row
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_row())
                    {
                        $dataTable->AddRow($row);
                    }
                    $result->free();
                    $dataSet[] = $dataTable;
                }
                if (!$this->dbconn->more_results()) {
                    break;
                }
            } while ($this->dbconn->next_result());
            $this->dbconn->close();
            //return the complete dataset
            return $dataSet;
        }
        else//save the error to member variables
        {
            $this->nErrorNumber = $this->dbconn->errno;
            $this->strErrorDesc = $this->dbconn->error;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is working Need to create a Class CTableData. Please make one and it will work great
.